# How do you spell professors when you include more than one professor in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

How do you spell professors when you include more than one professor in a sentence?
Do you say

> Professors' James and Leslie Atkins?

or

> Professors James and Leslie Atkins?

Answer (score 2):

> Professors James and Leslie Atkins.

An apostrophe at the end of the word would make “professors” [possessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive).

Note that this construction is only valid when you are referring to these two people:

1. Professor James Atkins
2. Professor Leslie Atkins

They have to both be professors and both have the surname “Atkins”. Most people will also interpret this as a sign that these two people are married to one another.

Comment: Although they could also be siblings, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Contradict me if you will, but the question you should be asking is not professors' or professors, but professors or professor's or professors'. Of the question you asked, the first would mean it was possessive, and the latter would be correctly. The first thing you should do is figure out what the addition to the end of the sentence(in this case, s', s, 's)really means. S means plural, 's means possessive, and s' is a plural possessive. Using this form, you can answer your question.